# How do I evaluate the limit of $(x-5+\sqrt{x+1})/\sqrt{x^2-9}$ as $x \to 3$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried substitution first. It won't work for this one.

When finding a limit of a fraction and in doubt, rationalize either the numerator or denominator.

Comment: yes i tried it .

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SE! Is this question about *Mathematica*, the software, or rather math? The latter should be addressed to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: If you want to evaluate the answer with Mathematica software, clarify the question to mention "with the Mathematica software". Otherwise, delete this question and move it to math.se. Remember to [format formulas with MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5):

Try [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html):

```
Limit[(x - 5 + Sqrt[1 + x])/Sqrt[x^2 - 9], x -> 3]
```

> 0